# Replace value in a regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have the next String in java:

```
|ABC|50200|100|50200|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|
```

So I need to replace the value `|50200|` (second one) with other value according to some decisions,but only need to replace the second one, how can I do, since replace or replaceAll don't work in this case. I was trying with some regex and appendReplacement but it did not work,also I need it to be as quick as possible, code below:

```
String event = "|ABC|50200|100|50200|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\|(\w*)\|(\d+)\|(\d+(\.\d{1,})*)\|(\d+(\.\d{1,})*)\|(\d+(\.\d{1,})*)\|\w+\|\w+\|\d{14}\|$");
Matcher mat = p.matcher(event);
StringBuffer aux = new StringBuffer();
mat.appendReplacement(aux, mat.group(5));
String newString = aux.toString();
```

But the value of newString is `50200`, so basically I want to replace it with `12345`, so the String would look like this `|ABC|50200|100|12345|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|`

Thanks in advance for your help

The thing is I have to use the regex to check the format of the String before doing the replace, because there could be other String with different formats

Comment: 1. Do you have to use a regular expression? 2. Is it always the second group?

Comment: why a regex? the format's simple enough. find the 4th `|`, then replace the next 5 characters. basic string operations, no need to involve a regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to find the second position, then `substring` around the value you want to replace.

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "|ABC|50200|100|50200|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|";

    String find = "50200";
    String replace = "12345";

    int firstOccur = s.indexOf(find);
    int secondOccur = s.indexOf(find, firstOccur+find.length());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.substring(0, secondOccur));
    sb.append(replace);
    sb.append(s.substring(secondOccur+find.length()));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    // |ABC|50200|100|12345|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since question has been tagged as regex and non-regex solution is possible but a bit longish here is a simple one line regex solution:

```
String data = "|ABC|50200|100|50200|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|";
String srch = "|50200|";
String repl = "|12345|";

String rdata = data.replaceFirst("^(.*?(\\|50200\\|).*?)\\2", "$1|12345|");
//=> |ABC|50200|100|12345|200|PRUEBA|ABC|20150220184512|
```

Regex `^(.*?(\|50200\|).*?)\2` finds 2nd instance of `|50200|` and captures everything before 2nd instance into captured group #1. We use backreference `$1` in replacement to put that captured text back.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW1bG8/1)

Comment: this one works perfectly if the first one and the second are the same, but it could also happen that both values are different, but I will need to change the second one not matter what

Comment: In that case use: **`rdata = data.replaceFirst("^(.*?\\|50200\\|.*?)\\|56789\\|", "$1|12345|");`**